# What differences are between the shell attributes/options that are set/unset by `set -o` and by `set` with another option?

Tags: bash

In bash, `set` is used to set or unset some shell option.

The option `-o option-name` and `+o option-name` are used to set and unset some shell options.

Other options than `-o` or `+o` of `set` are also used to set or unset some shell options.

What differences are between the shell attributes/options that are set/unset by `set -o` and by `set` with another option?

What are particular about the shell options set or unset by `set -o` and `set +o`, compared to the shell options set or unset by `set` with other options than `-o` and `+o`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between an existing single-letter option and its multiletter mnemonic; for example, `set -e` and `set -o errexit` are identical).

The reason why both forms exist, I suspect, is that the shell simply ran out of single-letter flags to represent the range of options desired. `-o` essentially provides an infinite number of options (limited only by the length of option names one can tolerate). Pre-existing flags were given option names as well for consistency and for use in self-documenting code. Option names without a corresponding single-letter flag are simply newer.